# AWS S3 Static website hosting で urlパラメータを指定したい

Tags: amazon-s3

#### 実現したいこと

urlパラメータを渡したい

**実行環境:**
React 15.3.1
Redux 3.5.2

AWS S3にSPAのHTMLとJavaScriptを配置
Static website hostingでwebサイトとして公開

なお、ローカル開発環境 (node + express) では発生していません。

#### 発生している問題

URLパラメータが指定されない。

以下のリンクをクリックすると

```html
<a href="/G002?kubun=0&data=2017-02-23&type=2">
```

到達先のURLではURLパラメータがなくなっている。
なお、URL中の `/G002` はディレクトリになります。

```
http://http://xxxx.dev.s3-website-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/G002/
```

#### 試したこと

アンカータグの `href` にフルパスを指定

```html
<a href="http://xxxx.dev.s3-website-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/G002?kubun=0&data=2017-02-23&type=2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URIの後ろに `/` (スラッシュ) をつけたところ、URLパラメータを渡すことができました。

**変更前:**

```html
<a href="/G002?kubun=0&data=2017-02-23&type=2">
```

**変更後:**

```html
<a href="/G002/?kubun=0&data=2017-02-23&type=2">
```